# How to cleanup after failed rsync?

Tags: rsync

I killed a local "rsync -ah" process.
It left junk files like ".abc.vmdk.zxivMN" in the target directory.
The junk files do not get deleted on consecutive "rsync -ah" runs.

Details:
I ran diff on both folders I was syncing and it reported:
"Only in /mnt/archive1/documents/general: .abc.vmdk.zxivMN"

**What is the best way to clean up the temporary rsync files ?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tell `rsync` to delete files not on the source, with `--delete-during` or `--delete-after`. Be careful and use this option only if you don't have legitimate files on the target that aren't there on the source.

See `man rsync`.

Of course, you could always manually delete the files you detected with `diff`...

Comment: This is no good when you're doing a copy rather than a move.

Answer (score 7):

I do it using

```
find -type f -iname ".*.*.??????" -ls
```

for test and

```
find -type f -iname ".*.*.??????" -delete
```

for clear

Answer (score -1):

I found the following command worked for me when trying to delete temp files left behind by rsync after a failed transfer.

```
find vod-content/ -path '*/.*' -print0 | xargs -0 -r rm -v
```

What this does is it finds all "hidden" files (files that begin with "." character) and passes them on to "rm" command to delete them.

A obvious **known issue** regarding the code above is if your contents contain hidden files then this command will delete those as well.

Answer (score -2):

I'm looking for a better solution but the only one I can think of is to move all `empty` files starting with a `.`, and having two further dots in them, to a trash folder (using `rm` is a bit risky):

```
find -type f -empty -iname ".*.*.*" | xargs -n 1 -d'\n' mv -v -t /tmp/
```

By no means foolproof.

Comment: Downvoted with no explanation